# Cannot connect to the configuration database after changing farm account

Tags: managed-account

I tried to replace the Farm Account. I created a new local account: farm.account.

In the SP admin, I went to Manage Service accounts (I think) and changed the account used, using the drop down, I selected: Farm Account.

I than selected to register a new managed account, and put the user name and password.

After that: I get the error: 
[image]

Running the configuration wizard. I get an error - from the error log:

```
    07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                      Successfully invoked the constructor for assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchServiceInstance, Microsoft.SharePoint.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C.  Object returned is SPSearchServiceInstance
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                    Leaving function TaskCommon.ReflectionHelperInvokeConstructor
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                    Successfully called the constructor for Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchServiceInstance, Microsoft.SharePoint.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                  Leaving function ServicesTask.InvokeServiceConstructor
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                  Found friendly name for serviceinstance Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchServiceInstance as SharePoint Foundation Search
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                  Calling SPServiceInstance.Update for instance Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchServiceInstance, service Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchService
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                  Successfully called SPServiceInstance.Update for instance Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchServiceInstance, service Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchService
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                  Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                    Resource id to be retrieved is ServicesSPServiceInstanceInstallSuccess for language English (United States)
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                    Resource retrieved id ServicesSPServiceInstanceInstallSuccess is Successfully installed service instance: {0}.
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                  Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                  Entering function TaskBase.OnTaskNotify
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                    Creating the OnTaskNotify event for task services
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                    Entering function TaskBase.FireTaskNotify
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                      Firing the OnTaskNotify event for task services
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                      Entering function PsconfigBaseForm.TaskNotifyEventHandler
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                        Invoking the UI thread with the task notification event
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                        Entering function ConfigurationProgressForm.InvokeTaskNotifyEventHandler
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                          A NotifyEventArgs event received in TaskNotifyEventHandler. Task: services NotifyEventArgs.EventCriticalityType: Successfully installed service instance: SharePoint Foundation Search. Message: info
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                          Acquiring the reader lock to retrieve the state
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                          Releasing the reader lock to retrieve the state
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                          Acquiring the reader lock to retrieve the state
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                          Releasing the reader lock to retrieve the state
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                          Updating the task notification additional message label
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                          Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                        Leaving function ConfigurationProgressForm.InvokeTaskNotifyEventHandler
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
07/15/2013 19:41:00  1  INF                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                        Sleeping an extra 1 ms so things don't go too fast for the user for this task
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                      Leaving function PsconfigBaseForm.TaskNotifyEventHandler
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                    Leaving function TaskBase.FireTaskNotify
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                  Leaving function TaskBase.OnTaskNotify
07/15/2013 19:41:00  11  INF                  Calling SPServiceInstance.Provision for instance Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchServiceInstance, service Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchService
07/15/2013 19:41:51  11  ERR                  Task services has failed with an unknown exception 
07/15/2013 19:41:51  11  ERR                  Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '00010012.wid'.
File name: '00010012.wid'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.DirTreeNode.Populate(DirectoryInfo d, Int64 maxlevel)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.DirTreeNode.Populate(DirectoryInfo d, Int64 maxlevel)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.DirTreeNode.Populate(DirectoryInfo d, Int64 maxlevel)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.DirTreeNode.Populate(DirectoryInfo d, Int64 maxlevel)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.DirTreeNode.Populate(DirectoryInfo d, Int64 maxlevel)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchServiceInstance.Synchronize(Boolean installGathererApplication, Boolean startIncrementalCrawl, Boolean startFullCrawl)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchServiceInstance.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstanceInConfigDB(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstanceToo, String serviceInstanceRegistryKeyName, Object sharepointServiceObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstances(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstancesToo, String serviceRegistryKeyName, Object sharepointServiceObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServices(Boolean provisionTheServicesToo)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
```

Comment: Have you ran the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard again, and specified the new account?

Comment: You need to run the the ol school stsadm `updatefarmcredentials`

Comment: @FalakMahmood thanks - feel free to post as an approved answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the the ol school stsadm `updatefarmcredentials`